# Windows.h or StdAfx.h, the first window example in Petzold's book "Programming Windows"

Tags: c++, winapi

I am learning winapi at the beginning from Petzold's book "Programming Windows", 5th edition.

The first example to create a window has a little problem to me. On the book, it's written that

```
#include "windows.h" (only this one)
```

But when I use Visual Studio C++ to (under Windows 7 64-bit) compile it, it complains that

*Warning    1   warning C4627: '#include "Windows.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use*

and

*Error  2   error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?*

After I change it to     `#include "StdAfx.h"`, it works fine.

So why I can't use `Windows.h`, and need to use `StdAfx.h`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your project configured to use [precompiled headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f7a897x.aspx).  In that case you put `windows.h` into `stdafx.h`, include `stdafx.h` in all compilation units that use PCH, and all is well.  Or, modify your project settings in the IDE to not use Precompiled Headers.

The book apparently assumes no PCH for clarity and independence from IDE vagaries.  Using PCH could speed up your build times if you develop large lists of header files, but for now it's probably simpler to not use this.

Comment: An alternate explanation is that the examples started out in the 1st edition of the book, before the compiler supported precompiled headers. :-)

Comment: @Bo - yes, that was what I was hinting at referring to the vagaries of the IDE.  The good old days, when `#include` meant what it said and nothing more.

Comment: Also, it should be `#include <windows.h>` rather than `#include "windows.h"`

Comment: But both of them works, so any difference for these two ways?

Answer (score -2):

In this case you want to change your precompiled headers you are using pch:

1. Go to the solution on the right side of a compiler.
2. Right click on it,
3. By clicking this you select the properties.
4. Then select the configuration properties and select All on the top
   left corner of a box.
5. Press ok.
6. Now select the project and right click on it.
7. Select the properties option.
8. Go to configuration and select c/c++ ,click on recomended headers,by
   clicking this select
9. Select no precompiled headers.
10. Press ok

Now your problem is solved